# Obtain power series expansion of $\frac{1}{(1+x)(1-2x)}$

Tags: power-series

Obtain power series expansion of $\frac{1}{(1+x)(1-2x)}$ and give the general term and radius of convergence.

Comment: You've given the general term, but not a series. Your term is not correct - how did you get it?

Comment: We only have convergence for $|x|\lt 1/2$. First use partial fractions on $\frac{1}{(1-x)(1+2x)}$.

Comment: @user1150537 How can the series possibly converge to $f(x)=\frac1{(x+1)(1-2x)}$ for $-1<x<1$? What value would it take in $x=\frac12$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting into partial fractions, you get
$$\frac{1}{(1+x)(1-2x)}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{2}{1-2x}\right)$$
If you're familiar enough with the series expansion for $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$, it should be easy to see that the series expansion in this case would simply be
$$\frac{1}{3}\left(\sum_{n\ge0}(-x)^n+2\sum_{n\ge0}(2x)^n\right)$$
which can be consolidated into one series:
$$\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n\ge0}\bigg((-1)^n+2^{n+1}\bigg)x^n$$
As for the radius of convergence, recall that the geometric series $\sum\limits_n x^n$ converges for $|x|<1$. You should be able to establish for yourself that in general, $\sum\limits_n (ax)^n$ converges for $|ax|<1$, or $|x|<\dfrac{1}{|a|}$. Then the R.O.C. must be $\dfrac{1}{|a|}$. This means the R.O.C. for $\sum\limits_n (-x)^n$ is $1$, while the R.O.C. for $\sum\limits_n (2x)^n$ is $\dfrac{1}{2}$. Note that both series converge only for $|x|<\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Alternatively, you can use the more compact form of the series expansion and apply the ratio test.

Comment: Yes that makes sense thank you very much, but what is the radius of convergence then? is it -1<x<1 or do I need to do ratio test and find it that way?

Comment: Also I did this: (is this not allowed?) $\frac{1}{(1+x)(1-2x)} =\frac{1}{(1+x)} \frac{1}{(1-2x)} $ and then found that just $\sum_{n\ge0} (-1)^n(x)^n(2x)^n $

Comment: @user2250537 I've added some more details.

Comment: Also, it would be better to show the work you've done in the actual question as opposed to the comments sections.

Comment: Yes that makes sense thank you so much!